# simple linear regression with Python with 10 lines of code

Tags: linear-regression

I am doing first steps in machine learning. Firstly, I try to create a simple algorithm, for example, linear regression of two variables. So, this manual (https://towardsdatascience.com/linear-regression-using-gradient-descent-in-10-lines-of-code-642f995339c0) is best example of coding this one. When I transfer this code, but it does not work. More correct, it prints unreal parameters of regression. Please, help me to overcome the problem. The script below.

```
x_1 = range(1,100)
y_1 = range(1,100)
N = float(len(y_1))
epochs=1000
m_current = b_current = 0
learning_rate=0.01
for i in range(epochs):
    for X,y in zip(x_1, y_1):
        y_current = (m_current * X) + b_current
        cost = (y-y_current)/N
        m_gradient = -(2/N)*(X * (y - y_current))
        b_gradient = -(2/N)*(y - y_current)
        m_current = m_current - (learning_rate * m_gradient)
        b_current = b_current - (learning_rate * b_gradient)
print(m_current)
print(b_current) 
print(cost)
/*print 
1.9999 i excpect 0.9999999 or 1
9.2333 i excpect 0.00000001 or 0
101.11 i excpect 0.1
*/
```

Comment: I run your exact code here in Python 3.6.2 and get m_current=0.9999511855632264, b_current=0.004857166613651627, and cost=2.528583373840214e-07.

Comment: "More correct, it prints unreal parametrs of regression" - could you explain what's going wrong, perhaps by telling us what exactly your results were, and how they differ from the results you expect?

Comment: I obtain the same results of @Hapalop. So probably you just have to restart your python session and rerun it.